# How to find equality of hr, min in date

Tags: java, datetime, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to find equality of hour, minutes in date (1 date in DST, 1 date after DST) in java. Both dates are in UTC. DST ends in UK 2020-10-26 2 AM, so in above example, hour and minute are equal.

1. Date1 = 2020-10-22T07:00:00+0000
2. Date2 = 2020-10-26T08:00:00+0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ZoneId zoneUk = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");

ZonedDateTime a = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-10-22T07:00:00+00:00").withZoneSameInstant(zoneUk);
ZonedDateTime b = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-10-26T08:00:00+00:00").withZoneSameInstant(zoneUk);
```

Notice the additional `:` in the time offset or it can't be parsed.

```
System.out.println(a); // 2020-10-22T08:00+01:00[Europe/London]
System.out.println(b); // 2020-10-26T08:00Z[Europe/London]
  
System.out.println(a.toLocalTime()); // 08:00
System.out.println(b.toLocalTime()); // 08:00
  
System.out.println(a.toLocalTime().equals(b.toLocalTime())); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Your date-time strings have Zone-Offset of `+0000` and therefore parsing them into `OffsetDateTime` (using an appropriate `DateTimeFormatter`) will be a more natural choice. Once you have parsed them into `OffsetDateTime`, convert them to the `ZonedDateTime` corresponding to the time-zone of the UK. As a final step, you need to get the local time part of the `ZonedDateTime`.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The given date-time strings
        String strDate1 = "2020-10-22T07:00:00+0000";
        String strDate2 = "2020-10-26T08:00:00+0000";

        // Define the formatter for the given date-time strings
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d'T'H:m:sZ");

        // ZoneId of the UK
        ZoneId tzLondon = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");

        // Get the corresponding date-time in the UK
        ZonedDateTime zdt1 = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDate1, formatter).atZoneSameInstant(tzLondon);
        ZonedDateTime zdt2 = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDate2, formatter).atZoneSameInstant(tzLondon);

        System.out.println(zdt1);
        System.out.println(zdt2);

        // Get local date from ZonedDateTime
        LocalTime lt1 = zdt1.toLocalTime();
        LocalTime lt2 = zdt2.toLocalTime();

        System.out.println(lt1);
        System.out.println(lt2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-22T08:00+01:00[Europe/London]
2020-10-26T08:00Z[Europe/London]
08:00
08:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.